# Customize the display template in SharePoint people search page

Tags: search

I have an inquiry regarding the display template in SharePoint people search page.

I have applied configured the peopleresults.aspx with the values that should be displayed, but I'm stuck on two issues now. I need to know how to move up the text (which includes the name, email and dept) so it can be horizontally align the image, and also to change the color of the name.

Your support is highly appreciated.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: do you use Online or Onprem version?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to do that. The easiest way to proto type that is to use the developer tool/F12 in Chrome